# docker-swarm running containers by pairs

Tags: docker-swarm

I have 5 nodes for docker-swarm and I have containers:

1. `redis` (official redis docker image)
2. `postgres` (official postgres docker image)
3. `data_processing` (a service which gets data from redis, does something with it and stores to postgres)
4. `data_loader` (a service which load data from network and pushes it to redis)
5. `reporter` (a service which reads from postgres database and sends statistics)

`nodes #1-3` must have group of services: "`data_processing`, `data_loader`, `redis`". Each node must have only these 3 services.

`node #4` must have `postgres` service, which should allocate 100% of resource.

`node #5` must have `reporter` service.

Question: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a placement constraint in order to deploy services on specific nodes. Example:

```
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints: [node.hostname == node1]
```

You can find more info here https://www.sweharris.org/post/2017-07-30-docker-placement/

Comment: Thanks you for reply. Yes, I know about this features. But my docker-compose file will be have all predefined containers. That is not what I have. How can I scale it when I have one or several more left node for this 3 containers?